# tensorflow:setting an array element with a sequence

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, nlp

when i use bilstm model to process NLP problem. i got the error while using session.run().I search on Google it seems that bad feed dict make the error. i print the input x shape, it is (100,), but i define it as that:[100, None,256].
how i can solve the error?
it's my evenrimont:
python:3.6
tensorflow:1.0.0
task:everty description has some tags, like stackoverflow, one question has some tags.i need to build a model to predict tags for questions.  my training input x is:[batch_size,None,word_embedding_size] a batch of question description, one description has some words, and one word is expressed as vector as length is 256. input y is:[batch_size,n_classes],

this is my model code:

```
    self.X_inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [self.n_steps,None,self.n_inputs])
    self.targets = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None,self.n_classes])
    #transpose the input x
    x = tf.transpose(self.X_inputs, [1, 0, 2])
    x = tf.reshape(x, [-1, self.n_inputs])
    x = tf.split(x, self.n_steps)

    # lstm cell
    lstm_cell_fw = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(self.hidden_dim)
    lstm_cell_bw = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(self.hidden_dim)

    # dropout
    if is_training:
        lstm_cell_fw = tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(lstm_cell_fw, output_keep_prob=(1 - self.dropout_rate))
        lstm_cell_bw = tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(lstm_cell_bw, output_keep_prob=(1 - self.dropout_rate))

    lstm_cell_fw = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([lstm_cell_fw] * self.num_layers)
    lstm_cell_bw = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([lstm_cell_bw] * self.num_layers)

    # forward and backward
    self.outputs, _, _ = tf.contrib.rnn.static_bidirectional_rnn(
        lstm_cell_fw,
        lstm_cell_bw,
        x,
        dtype=tf.float32
    )
```

feed_dict like that:

```
feed_dict={
              self.X_inputs: X_train_batch,
              self.targets: y_train_batch
          }
```

the X_train_batch is some sentence, they have such shape, [100,None,256], the'None' means, input sentence has not the same length, from 10 to 1500,i just get the real length. maybe it occur the error? 
My question is:do you padding the sentence length as the same, or reshape the inputs while doing such nlp work?

Comment: Please rework your question to include more useful information. What error are you talking about? Try to reduce your code sample to the shortest possible, while still evoking the error. Less work for the ones helping you means you have better chances of being helped.

Comment: Most likely you are trying to combine images or arrays that differ in shape.

Comment: @lenz thanks for your respond, i edit my question again.